# NDK build error: "fatal error: stdint.h: No such file or directory" on Mac Os X

Tags: android, android-ndk, ndk-build

I use the following build command to build [OpenH264](https://github.com/cisco/openh264) project.

```
make OS=android ARCH=arm64 NDKROOT=~/Library/Android/android-ndk-r10d/ TARGET=android-12
```

But i got the following error:

```
/Users/jerikc/Library/Android/android-ndk-r10d/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-android/4.9/include-fixed/limits.h:168:61: error: no include path in which to search for limits.h
 #include_next <limits.h>  /* recurse down to the real one */
                                                             ^
In file included from ./codec/common/inc/typedefs.h:48:0,
                 from ./codec/common/inc/wels_common_defs.h:37,
                 from codec/common/src/common_tables.cpp:33:
/Users/jerikc/Library/Android/android-ndk-r10d/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-android/4.9/include/stdint.h:9:26: fatal error: stdint.h: No such file or directory
 # include_next <stdint.h>
                          ^
compilation terminated.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You request target platform 12, which does not support **arm64**. The lowest **TARGET** for this architecture is **android-21**.

There is probably some glitch in the script, and we must set the platform twice in the build command:

```
make OS=android ARCH=arm64 TARGET=android-21 NDKLEVEL=21
```

Make sure that `NDKROOT` and `PATH` are set correctly.

Comment: The error still exist by `make OS=android NDKROOT=~/Library/Android/android-ndk-r10d/ ARCH=arm64 TARGET=android-21`

Comment: For some reason, we must set the platform twice. The answer updated.

Comment: Old error didn't occur, but got a new error:`codec/common/src/cpu-features.o: error adding symbols: File in wrong format collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

Comment: Please try `make -B OS=android ARCH=arm64 TARGET=android-21 NDKLEVEL=21` for full rebuild

Comment: It works fine for me now. Thanks for your great help. Accept and upvote. Please update the answer. Thanks again.

Comment: There is no need to update the answer. The build did not work for you because some intermediates were stuck after you failed attempt with default NDKLEVEL=12. This is exactly the reason why we have the **`-B`** flag for **make** command.