# Ffmpeg not compiling

Tags: android, ffmpeg, compilation

I'm trying to compile ffmpeg 4.0 for Android (using Ubuntu 64 bit) but I can not get it to work.
I was able to compile it for Linux itself fairly fast, but now struggling using the NDK. I'm unexperienced with this so I might have some major flaw somewhere. All paths and files exist. Github tutorials are extremely outdated and don't work as well for me with different errors.

Getting following error:

```
In file included from ./libavformat/internal.h:24:0,
             from libavdevice/alldevices.c:23:
/home/lit/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi- 
4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/lib/gcc/arm-linux- 
androideabi/4.9.x/include/stdint.h:9:26: fatal error: stdint.h: No such file 
or directory
# include_next <stdint.h>
                      ^
compilation terminated.
ffbuild/common.mak:60: recipe for target 'libavdevice/alldevices.o' failed
make: *** [libavdevice/alldevices.o] Error 1
```

My build script:

```
SYSROOT=/home/lit/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/platforms/android-14/arch-arm/
TOOLCHAIN=/home/lit/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi- 
4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64

cd ffmpeg/ffmpeg && \
PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH" PKG_CONFIG_PATH="$HOME/ffmpeg_build/lib/pkgconfig" 
./configure \
--prefix="$HOME/ffmpeg_build" \
--pkg-config-flags="--static" \
--extra-cflags="-O3 -Wall -pipe -ffast-math -fstrict-aliasing -Werror=strict- aliasing -Wno-psabi -Wa,--noexecstack -DANDROID -DNDEBUG-march=armv5te -mtune=arm9tdmi -msoft-float"\
--extra-ldflags="-L$HOME/ffmpeg_build/lib" \
--bindir="$HOME/bin" \
--arch=arm \
--target-os=linux \
--enable-cross-compile \
--cross-prefix=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- \
--cpu=armv5te \
--sysroot=$SYSROOT \
--enable-gpl \
--enable-small \
--enable-nonfree && \

PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH" make && \
make -j2 && \
make install && \
hash -r
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

[see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33239915/ndk-build-error-fatal-error-stdint-h-no-such-file-or-directory-on-mac-os-x)
it seems the level of platform caused the problem.
try android-21 in SYSROOT.

Comment: Same result. But why would that be? I'm not compiling for arm64.